# Picture doesn't resize vertically/not centered vertically

Tags: html, css, resize, responsiveness

The picture (mr bean as of now) resizes fine when the browser is shrunk horizontally but doesn't do anything if the browser is shrunk vertically. I want that picture to be kept in the center of the page always.

https://jsbin.com/mehihimevi/edit?html,css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always the table-cell method https://jsbin.com/xirevixexo/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching the problem wrongly - looks like you're using `skeleton.css` framework? Most frameworks are meant to contain grids of content and what you want to achieve is not applicable in grid-related layout.

I tried doing what you wanted to achieve on jsfiddle, it will probably need tweaks but I think it's a good start for you.

https://jsbin.com/lotena/edit?html,css,output